# Fill up a form field through cookies or local storage on external website

Tags: cookies, local-storage

I am looking for a way to fill up an input field on an external website through a cookie or local storage. I have a button on my site that takes you to the external page which is a registration form. There is a number input field which must be populated from my page, but it's always the same number (fixed number). So i would like for my customers to have the number already filled in when they open the registration form instead of having to fill it in themselves.
I saw this being done in another website so i know it's possible but i don't have any experience with cookies or local storage to replicate it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have control of the other website as well, you could try the solution described here: [Cross-Domain Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342140/cross-domain-cookies).
I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Vincent. I don't control the other website. My site just leads to theirs for the registration part. I saw another website like mine somehow planting a cookie in my browser to fill in an input field and make the field non-interactive. Is there a way for me to set up a cookie from my site for another website or can they only be for my own site?

Comment: @Stoycho I'm afraid you can't use cookies for that. The only two methods to save user's data in browser are Cookies and Localstorage. Both seem not useful in this case. Another way would be having the data stored as parameters in the url. But for that solution the other website should be configured to be able to read that.

Comment: Thanks, I am guessing that the other website similar to mine might be working together with the main site and therefore they pass parameters as you said and the main website reads them to populate the field and make it inactive.